# Notepad++, my regex that works elsewhere, seem not work with Notepad++ search

Tags: notepad++, regex

Hello i got following regex

```
height="(\d*\.\d{3})\d*cm"
```

And problem, while it works on site i did designed it http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it wont work with notpad++, could someone help me correcting that Regex to make it work with Notepad++? And maybe give link to some guide that explains these diffrences between diffrent variations of RegEx?

**More details**

Im trying to use it for search and replace of some values in xml file, ofcourse regular expressions option is selected in Notepad++ search box. Alternatively i would need regex that allows to find

```
nameoftag="<something>"
```

and here is example of what document, I'm working on, looks like

```
<draw:frame text:anchor-type="page" text:anchor-page-number="1" draw:z-index="41" draw:name="Picture 23" draw:style-name="abe" svg:width="9.207cm" svg:height="6.913cm" svg:x="0cm" svg:y="0cm">
```

Comment: A little more detail please. What are you trying to do? What does it do that you dont expect?

Comment: Provided sample data and regular expression causes `height="6.913cm"` to be selected when I run it through Notepad++'s Find & replace. Settings: Regular expression, wrap around, direction down. Everything else is unchecked / deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems was most likely caused either by old version of Notepad++, my problem occured with version **5.9.6.2 (UNICODE)** or because of plugin **Oberon2LexerU.dll** that got disabled during update to version **6.1.5 (UNICODE)**. Which was exact cause i could not actually determine since i followed hunch when I've readed comment by *Darth Android* i figured that there might be problem with version i got. After update all seems to work as expected.

Thanks for help!